# Accessing a global variable outside a class

Tags: php, class, global-variables

I am using JpGraph and CodeIgniter. In JpGraph, you can define a Callback function to add some properties.

In my tests, everything was correct, I used :

```
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) 
{
$datax[$i] = $data[$i][0];
$datay[$i] = -$data[$i][1];

$format[strval($datax[$i])][strval($datay[$i])] = array($data[$i][2],$data[$i][3]);
}
```

Then I specify the callback :

```
 $sp1->mark->SetCallbackYX("FCallback");
```

And my function :

```
function FCallback($aYVal,$aXVal) 
{
    global $format;
    return array($format[strval($aXVal)][strval($aYVal)][0],'',
     $format[strval($aXVal)][strval($aYVal)][1],'','');
}
```

But, with CodeIgniter, I build my graph in a Class, so I can't use global var $format.  There is a way to access the var $format outside the class ? Thanks.

Comment: windmills. they are everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to find a way to pass the $format variable into the FCallback function rather than using the global scope. But, if you need to you could try using the $GLOBALS array.

Pass the $format function into the $GLOBALS array within your controller class

```
$GLOBALS['format'] = $format;
```

Then within the FCallback function you would grab the variable using the reverse.

```
$format = $GLOBALS['format'];
```

Comment: Damn ! So simple ... Thanks a lot, sorry for my question, I search but not with the right words.